# SharedPreference - How to toast only once when Activity recieves the data

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

how can i toast only once when my `Activity 2` receive's data / value from my `Activity 1` ? , I am trying to unlock a `button`  when he receive the same `value`  from the other activity. 
Below is my code

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("UnlockPreTestFour", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
             final int scorePre = sharedPreferences.getInt("ScoreFour", 0);
               if(scorePre !=0){
            Toast.makeText(grade_four.this, "Button Unlock!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      }
```

in my code after the `Activity 2` receives the same value from `Activity 1`, 
it always `toast` because it already has a `value` , can someone help me, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Boolean hasReceivedData = false

SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("UnlockPreTestFour", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
         final int scorePre = sharedPreferences.getInt("ScoreFour", 0);

           //check to see if you have received the data
           if(scorePre !=0 && hasReceivedDate == false){
                Toast.makeText(grade_four.this, "Button Unlock!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                //set variable to ensure data is only loaded once
                hasReceivedData = true;
             }
```

Here is a simple and kind of hacky answer.  Your `hasReceivedData` variable will have to be passed onConfigurationChanged.  I hope this helps!

Comment: it still display toast message when i'm  opening the activity,